# Is there std quoted equivalent allowing different left and right delim char

Tags: c++, std, stdout

Is there an equivalent to std::quoted that would allow for wrapping the output string into lets say brackets {} ?? Therefore allowing to set left delim char and right delim char and escaping both of these inside the "quoted" string??

And if there is no such equivalent, why is that so??

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted

Comment: I see all variants of this method allowing custom delimiters.

Comment: Now if you want the left and right delimiters to be different, you are out of luck.

Comment: *And if there is no such equivalent, why is that so?*  Because someone hasn't written it yet.